# How can I pass value of selected auto complete box to next autocomplete box as a argument from "View argument" section of cck field?

Tags: drupal, view, field, cck, arguments

I have created a product review content type with some fields for categories and reviews.
I have 2 auto fill fields one for categories  and one field for product selection which is also auto fill.
Created views to attached with these fields so I can get the output of categories as per passed "View argument".

When user will select the category from category auto fill box I want to pass that selected value as a argument to the product auto fill box. So the products will come as per selected categories.

I have searched for this on forums but not got the proper answer. Does anybody has idea about this feature?
Please see following image for reference.
[image: Product autocomplete box should be filled as per selected category]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link can help you: http://groups.drupal.org/node/3471
This example is for Drupal 5, but the basics for 6 and 7 are the same: custom JS to handle the Category Level 1 value, then post it to some MENU_CALLBACK on your site, which calls the View to get nodes with its IDs based on passed argument of Category level 1.
Anyway, if there are some difficulties, I can generate some code for D6 or D7.

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution Alexey. I will definitively try it out today and let you know the result of this code sample.

Comment: I have tried this code but something is going wrong nothing is happening when added my values in-place of code variables. Alexey, can you provide the code for Drupal 6 with given example by me. It will really help me to understood the concept. Thanks for your great support.